# Local properties of loop spaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology, loop-spaces

It is well-known that $$\pi_k(X)=\pi_{k-1}(\Omega X)$$
and in particular $\Omega X$ is path-connected iff $X$ is simply connected.

I'm looking for a reference for the corresponding (semi-)local property:

$\Omega X$ is (semi-)locally path-connected iff $X$ is (semi-)locally simply connected.

Comment: One implication ($\Leftarrow$) is clear; I am not at all sure that the opposite implication holds.

Comment: You will have to be careful with basepoints at least for a rigorous statement.